# how to understand this attributive clause?

Tags: clauses, parsing

> “We believe a product that addresses the more than 70 percent of global wireless subscribers **that are unsubsidized pre-paid** is necessary in order for Apple to grow its EPS next year,” Piecyk writes.

What are unsubsidized pre-paid?  "Global wireless subscribers" or "the more than 70 percent of global wireless subscribers"?

Comment: Kaili, if you are satisfied with the answer, accept it.  If it is useful, vote it up.  If it is not useful, vote it down.

Comment: I am very satisfied with it, so I voted it up now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *pre-paid* wireless telephone plan is one in which users pay into their accounts, which are debited with each use of the service. This contrasts with plans where users are charged a fixed amount monthly for services up to a specified limit.

*Unsubsidized* here refers not to the telephone service but to the telephone itself. Typically subscribers to a telephone service are constrained to use of specific instruments which are made available to them by the service provider at a substantially reduced price. These instruments are called *subsidized*, because it appears that the service provider 'subsidizes' the price. *Unsubsidized* telephones are those which users purchase for themselves on the open market.

*Global wireless subscribers* are all subscribers to wireless telephone services everywhere in the world. More these 70% of these, says Piecyk, use pre-paid plans and purchase their own phones. Formally, *that are unsubsidized pre-paid* modifies *70 percent*. He identifies these users as a specific group by employing the article *the*:

> ... **the** more than 70 percent of global wireless subscribers that are unsubsidized pre-paid...

Consequently,

> We believe a product that addresses **these users** is necessary in order for Apple to grow its EPS next year.

Comment: So, this product does not address "70% of unsubsidized pre-paid global wireless subscribers" , but address "all unsubsidized pre-paid global wireless subscribers"...Now I understand. Thanks a lot.